# factors of $100000$

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, problem-solving

Let $S$ be the set of all positive integer divisors of $100000$. How many numbers are the product of $2$ distinct elements of $S$?

factors of 100000

Let $100000 = 2^55^5$ be divisible by $2^a5^b$ and $2^b5^c$. Then $a, b, c, d$ are nonnegative integers less than $6$. Since $0 \le a + c, b + d \le 10$, there exist $11^2 = 121$ possible values for $(2^a5^b)(2^c5^d) = 2^{a + c}5^{b + d}$. $1, 2, 5, 2^{10}5^{10}$ are the only values that cannot equal the product of $2$ distinct factors of $100000$. As a result, the answer is $121 - 4 = \boxed{117}$.

Am I right? Any other solutions?

Comment: 117 is the right answer, but $2 = 1\times 2$. Both $1$ and $2$ are distinct elements of $S$. $2^0 5^0$, $2^{10} 5^0$, $2^0 5^{10}$, and $2^{10} 5^{10}$ are the four values that need to be excluded from 121.